Cosmological redshift and distance calculus
I am somewhat puzzled when it comes to understanding the general relationship between the cosmological redshift of a galaxy and its distance, and none of the other questions in the forum have clarified my doubt.
In particular, is there any general formula that relates the redshift z to the distance, without any approximation (such as small z)? I mention this because even though z is related to the scale factor a(t), this factor keeps changing as light propagates towards Earth. Moreover, z could be so high that the velocity would be relativistic.

One important point to clarify is that the idea that "z could be so high that the velocity would be relativistic" doesn't really make sense from a physical perspective. Making a comparison of velocity to determine if something is relativistic requires your objects to be "local" (i.e. nearby) each other. Just because $z>1$ and therefore $v = cz > 1$ doesn't mean anything is going faster than the speed of light in its local frame.
There is a generic formula for comoving distance to a given redshift $z_1$, which can be derived from the Freedman equations:
$$d_c(z_1) = \frac{c}{H_0}\int_0^{z_1} dz \left[\Omega_r(1+z)^4+\Omega_m(1+z)^3+\Omega_k(1+z)^2+\Omega_\Lambda\right]^{-1/2}$$
where $c$ is the speed of light, $H_0$ is the local Hubble constant, $\Omega_r$ is the radiation density of the universe, $\Omega_m$ is the matter density, $\Omega_k$ is related to non-zero curvature, and $\Omega_\Lambda$ is the dark energy density. All densities are at $z=0$ (i.e. present day) and their redshift evolution is captured in the (1+z)-type factors depending on how their energy density scales with the expansion.
There are various calculators online where you can plug in your favorite numbers and calculate a comoving distance: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/help/cosmology_calc.html

Thank you very much! But I am a bit confused about the fact that the densities $\Omega_i$ can change during the propagation of light (obviously only for objects that are really far). Moreover, could you provide the source of the equation? I could not find this formula.

It is derived in pretty much all advanced cosmology textbooks. The first one I grabbed off my table, Weinberg Cosmology, has it on page 76. You can find PDFs of it online.

These are all densities at the z=0, the redshift evolution is expressed by those (1+z) factors. I edited my answer to specify this.
